Why 'state' is not 'parsererror' when server responded with 500 and broken JSON?
In this case,
 $.ajax( '/', { error: function handleError( jqXHR, state, errorThrown ) { ... } } );

when server responses with 500 and broken JSON, eg. '@#$@#%', the state contains error instead of expected parsererror.
Though if server responses with 200 and the same broken JSON, then the state contains as expected parsererror.
My jQuery version is 3.7.1

Simple... HTTP status takes precedence over body parse errors. I'm not even sure jQuery bothers trying to parse the response for anything outside the 2xx range

To properly answer your question, you'd need to ask the jQuery developer(s) why they decided to do it this way

If there's a network or protocol error of some kind, there's no reason to expect the data to be valid.
